# Quartz Custom Logger: The message function is null

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I have added a custom logger to my application, basically straight from the docs:

```
LogProvider.SetCurrentLogProvider(new ConsoleLogProvider());

private class ConsoleLogProvider : ILogProvider
{
    public Logger GetLogger(string name)
    {
        return (level, func, exception, parameters) =>
        {
            if (func != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[" + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + "] [" + level + "] " + func(), parameters);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[" + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + "] [" + level + "] Func is null");
            }

            return true;
        };
    }

    public IDisposable OpenNestedContext(string message)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IDisposable OpenMappedContext(string key, string value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Strangely enough, I get called a lot with func == null. In those cases, parameters is object[0], but level is of varying levels, indicating I guess that these  are valid calls.

Can anyone explain what these log messages are? 
Is there more info to fetch elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I might have an answer (but it would be interesting to hear from someone who knows more).

I found the following code in LogExtensions.cs:

```
static class LogExtensions
    {
        internal static readonly object[] EmptyParams = new object[0];

        /// <summary>
        ///     Check if the <see cref="LogLevel.Debug"/> log level is enabled.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="logger">The <see cref="ILog"/> to check with.</param>
        /// <returns>True if the log level is enabled; false otherwise.</returns>
        public static bool IsDebugEnabled(this ILog logger)
        {
            GuardAgainstNullLogger(logger);
            return logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, null, null, EmptyParams);
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Check if the <see cref="LogLevel.Error"/> log level is enabled.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="logger">The <see cref="ILog"/> to check with.</param>
        /// <returns>True if the log level is enabled; false otherwise.</returns>
        public static bool IsErrorEnabled(this ILog logger)
        {
            GuardAgainstNullLogger(logger);
            return logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, null, null, EmptyParams);
        }
:
:
```

It appears as if the checks for "IsXXXEnabled()" are implemented as dummy calls to Log(), testing the return value. If you log an error and Log() returns false, that means that the Error level is not enabled.

So all those log messages in my output are probably just tests for enabled log levels.